# seek to code properly

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I a GUI which contains two JTextField and one JComboBox, based on the content of the JComboBox, I will show another JPanel that contains a set of components.

so I proceeded as follows (it worked) but I want to know if I coded properly.

I created a class that filled HashMap (String, JPanel) .... the string is the content of my JComboBox

```
public class MapGui {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    HashMap<String, JPanel> map;

    public MapGui() {
        map.put("1", new location());
        map.put("2", new vente());
        .......
    }
```

and every time I call the method:

```
public JPanel getPanel(String s) {
return map.get(s);

}
```

and new location () and new vente () and ..... are classes that inherit from JPanel and contain all components.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a map for that purpose. What you described is the behavior of a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Basically, you create a "Deck" panel that uses the aforementioned layout manager, add the cards (JPanel) you want (in your case *location* and *vente*) to the deck panel, and lastly add the deck panel to the frame.

To mechanize the hiding and showing of panels, simply use listeners. The link I provided shows **EXACTLY** what you need to do to implement what you are asking.